# How is Lucene's IndexOutput "random-access"?

Tags: java, io, lucene

The Lucene API offers a class [IndexInput](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/store/IndexInput.html) that implements "a random-access input stream", and includes methods to set the position of a cursor for subsequent reads ([seek(long)](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/store/IndexInput.html#seek(long))) and to get the current position of the cursor from where subsequent reads will be performed ([getFilePointer()](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/store/IndexInput.html#getFilePointer())).

The Lucene API also offers a parallel [IndexOutput](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/store/IndexInput.html#getFilePointer()) class that implements "a random-access output stream", however, the API for this class *does not* have a seek(long) method. Lacking the means to position a cursor for writing, how and in what sense is an IndexOutput a random-access output stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, as I figured it out:

The documentation is wrong. Lucene's IndexOutput does not implement a random-access output stream since version 5.

The seek(long) method that would be necessary for this purpose [was deprecated with version 4.1](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/IndexOutput.html#seek(long)), and both its signature and the implementing classes that supported it were removed from Lucene's source code with version 5, but the interface's description has not been updated to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Lucene never writes by random positioning. This would be costly to do so. Even if you update an existing document, it deletes the document and creates new one with updates applied. And deleted document sits there but marked as deleted in bitset data structure. Whenever merge happens or flush happens it will get deleted from index. This way lucene avoids writing to random position in file. So always appends to the existing file if it needs to write.

---

For reading it needs to do seek to read correct block of data while searching for looking up posting lists and so on.

Comment: Right, that is what Lucene does for reading and writing its own binary formats, but their I/O API (which is amazingly fast...) can be used for other purposes... My idea was to use it as a replacement for [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), for which IndexInput works for reading, but I couldn't figure out how to implement the writing... I guess the API docs are lying then?

Comment: You cannot use it for other purposes. it is not faster than java's existing api, in fact it uses java api under the hood(ByteBuffer). So if you are planning to use it for other purposes outside of lucene, you won't get any faster than what java offers and not doing right, since it is internal api of lucene and not designed for usage outside of lucene.

Comment: I think you mean "you shouldn't", as I certainly *can* use it, as it is a public API and is not marked as "experimental" or "internal", as others. Incidentally, in my experience, it does perform faster than the equivalent Java abstractions, and I'm confident that I can devise a way to do it right, but that issue is besides the point. Thanks for your concern, though.

Comment: @gorgonzola 1. *It uses the Java API under the hood.* 2. It doesn't have a seek method, or any of the primitive read and write methods, so it can't replace RandomAccessFile. You're not making sense,

Comment: @EJP: 1.- Lucene versions < 5 implement their own version of DataOuputStream using OutputStreamIndexOutput which in turn uses BufferedOuputStream as I/O backend, but performs all of the data encoding using its own logic. This does indeed perform faster than using Java's DataOutputStream. 2.- The IndexOutput interface in Lucene version < 5 does indeed implement seek(long). DataOutput, which is IndexOutput's super class, does indeed implement the primitive write methods that could allow it to be used as a replacemente for RandomAccessFile.

Only after version 5 did Lucene move to using NIO.